# How to get cell value from another excel sheet based on multiple list conditions

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I apologise if this comes across as a newbie query, but I have been stumped by this for some time.

I am building an excel spreadsheet for my staff to be able to compare stock listings easily and automatically based on reference data held in a different sheet within the same workbook.

The difficulty is that I want to pull this reference data based on the values chosen from a total of 6 conditional drop down lists I have created.

Based on what is selected, the values on say Sheet 1 will display the relevant values from Sheet 2 automatically (i.e. if one of the list options is changed, the "results" will update with the associated data automatically).

I have tried using lookup functions, arrays and nested if functions, but I have been unable to get it to work properly - probably due to my own lack of depth of knowledge for this type of coding. As such I am looking for advice about the best way to code this function requirement.

The format of what I am trying to do is this:

Sheet 1 - The 'GUI'
This sheet has the dropdown lists and the "displayed results" section

```
dd1 - State (6 options)
dd2 - Product Type (4 options)
dd3 - Product Brand (3 options)
dd4 - Product variation 1 (eg model) (say, 2 options)
dd5 - Product variation 2 (eg colour) (5 options)
dd6 - Product variation 3 (eg size) (3 options)
```

Sheet 2 - Reference data

```
Table 1 - ACT products and variations
Table 2 - VIC products and variations 
Table 3 - NSW products and variations etc and so on...
```

Based on choices above in Sheet1, I want the product & price to be listed in cells below. Currently I have conditional functions listing the avail options based on the choice made for the prev list working fine.

I need it so that:

```
IF dd1 = "ACT" AND dd2 = "Mobile" AND dd3 = "Apple" AND dd4 = "iPhone" AND dd5 = "white" AND dd6 = "128Gb"
```

Then

The results cell, say Sheet1!C10, will reflect the price of the item based on a table of data lists in Sheet2 (say for eg the listed value is in Sheet 2, Cell A5)

But if say the list choices change, eg dd3 was changed to "Samsung", then the lists will auto update because of the conditional formatting already; but I then want the results to be updated accordingly (eg the price listed based on the new choices will then reflect Sheet2!B3).

Because of the many options and variations, there are many tables in Sheet 2 for reference, so the 'IF' statement to cover all these options would be massive and convoluted.

Is there a relatively concise way of writing vb code for this function to suit?

My current code under the worksheet_change sub

```
    If Range("D10").Value = "ACT" And (Range("D11").Value = "Mobile" And (Range("D13").Value = "Samsung" And (Range("D14").Value = "S7") And (Range("D15").Value = "Black") And (Range("D16").Value = "128"))))) Then

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F20").Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C5").Value2

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F29").Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C6").Value2

ElseIf Range("D10").Value = "ACT" And (Range("D11").Value = "Mobile" And (Range("D13").Value = "Samsung" And (Range("D14").Value = "S7") And (Range("D15").Value = "Black") And (Range("D16").Value = "256"))))) Then

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F21").Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C8").Value2

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F22").Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C9").Value2

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F29").Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C10").Value2
```

'and so on. With all the variations, there's prob going to be approx 20+ elseif statements.

```
End If
```

Ive only pasted 2x sections for the purpose of this request. I can copy it down or adjust the code accordingly for each option.

Ive not used nor written arrays before (successfully i.e.) so I have no clue/understanding if that is a better way, but i have written vba for basic functions and macros before; but im open to learn.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You have a good description of what you are trying to achieve but what you haven't provided is what you have tried so far? i.e. have you written any VBA? or made an attempt to achieve this with formulas? At SO we tend not to write the code for you but instead help you with yours. It might also be worth posting sample screen prints of your sheets and how you want `Sheet1` to look like

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Sorry for the late reply, just got back from long weekend. Wasn't expecting such a fast response. Ive updated the post with my current code. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: It's a little bit complex helping you without looking at your sheet, in this case I would ask if you can edit your answer by uploading an image of your reference tables. What i'm trying to say is that if one of the dropdown list options matches one of your tables column name we can use loops and accomplish what you are looking for